# Get the next element of list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of sentences like:

```
lst = ['A B C D','E F G H I J','K L M N']
```

What i did is

```
l = []
for i in lst:
    for j in i.split():
        print(j)
        l.append(j) 

first = l[::2]
second = l[1::2]

[m+' '+str(n) for m,n in zip(first,second)]
```

The Output i got is

```
lst = ['A B', 'C D', 'E F', 'G H', 'I J', 'K L', 'M N']
```

The Output i want is:

```
lst = ['A B', 'B C','C D','E F','F G','G H','H I','I J','K L','L M','M N']
```

I am struggling to think how to achieve this.

Comment: `[i for x in map(lambda x: x.split(' '), lst) for i in map(' '.join, zip(x[:-1], x[1:]))]`

Comment: Did you try my answer? It's shorter than the accepted one

Comment: Your solution is already correct if you replace `::2` with `:` in both places

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First format your list of string into a list of list, then do a mapping by `zip`.

```
i = [i.split() for i in lst]

f = [f"{x} {y}" for item in i for x,y in zip(item,item[1::])]

print (f)

#['A B', 'B C', 'C D', 'E F', 'F G', 'G H', 'H I', 'I J', 'K L', 'L M', 'M N']
```

Comment: +1. Can also condense into a one-liner if you replace `i` with the first list comprehension itself (current code is more readable though)

Comment: the `[x for x in i.split(" ")]` could be just `i.split()`... Nice solution +1

Comment: @Tomerikoo You are right. Force of habit to always write what I split on :)

Comment: I was referring to the whole list comprehension as `split` already returns a list and not a generator or something... I believe it makes it a bit more readable

Comment: Cool, if I could, would be +2 :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're flattening the whole list and dividing to couples when you want to divide to subsequent couples only the inner elements. So for that we will perform the operation on each element separatly:

```py
lst = ['A B C D','E F G H I J','K L M N']

res = []
for s in lst:
    sub_l = s.split()
    for i in range(len(sub_l)-1):
        res.append("{} {}".format(sub_l[i], sub_l[i+1]))
print(res)
```

Gives:

```
['A B', 'B C', 'C D', 'E F', 'F G', 'G H', 'H I', 'I J', 'K L', 'L M', 'M N']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
nested = []
for item in lst:
    item = (' '.join(item).split())
    for ix in range(len(item) - 1):
        nested.append(' '.join(item[ix:ix + 2]))

print (nested)
```

output:

```
['A B', 'B C', 'C D', 'E F', 'F G', 'G H', 'H I', 'I J', 'K L', 'L M', 'M N']
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo is correct, the output is slightly different, I was doing the same as @ncica. You'll probably need to add some `if` condition to not append a few elements

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using Regex:

```
import re
lst = ['A B C D','E F G H I J','K L M N']
result = re.findall(r'(?=(\b\w+?\b \b\w+?\b))', str(lst))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['A B', 'B C', 'C D', 'E F', 'F G', 'G H', 'H I', 'I J', 'K L', 'L M', 'M N']
```

Comment: Thnks for the answer...Yes i have already tried it and its not working it gives only the last and first value of both words....every words in list is actual word not an alphabet.

Comment: @jamesjoyce I've edited it so now it will work for words. And please be more specific in your questions in future because you didn't mention that it would be words and not just letters.